# Script to check if user belongs to sudo group

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

I think I'm fairly close to checking if a user belongs to the sudo group in Ubuntu, then add a line to the sudoers file. Except when I look in the sudoers file, I see:

```
$IDUSER ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/myscript
```

instead of that users name, eg.

```
bob ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/myscript
```

Here is what I have:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -e

IDUSER=$(grep -Po '^sudo.+:\K.*$' /etc/group)

if [ `id -u $IDUSER 2>/dev/null || echo -1` -ge 0 ]; then 
    echo '$IDUSER ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/myscript' >> /etc/sudoers

else
    echo "Script failed..."
fi
```

Ideally, I'd like to add all users in the sudo group to the sudoers file.

Thank you.

Comment: Hm, why would you want to do that? I think you can reference all members of the group in one line like with `%sudoers` instead of the user name but should check docs thoroughly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In single quotes `'`, bash variables don't get expanded. Use double quotes `"` instead in the line with `echo`.

If you're just trying to let users in the group sudo run this command, though, just add the line:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/myscript
```

to the `/etc/sudoers` file. The `%` sign denotes a group, here.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that did the trick. Any suggestions for adding all users in the sudo group to the sudoers file using the above script?

Comment: @sh_newbie I added some information to my answer. Your script would do the job as written (though it would do annoying things like duplicate lines if you ran it twice, and there might be some subtle bugs), but it's generally better not to modify the sudoers file in any script- it's pretty easy to screw something up.

Comment: I understand the risk of editing the sudoers file with anything other than visudo, but did my research first and decided it was safe to do through a script. This will end up as an Debian package, so I can use pre/postinst scripts to tidy the sudoers file.

Comment: @sh_newbie The main risk is if a crash occurs: for instance, what happens if a crash occurs during such tidying? Or just if your script has some subtle bug that only occurs if the `sudo` group has at least 4097 users or something silly like that? Anyway, I just thought it was worth mentioning the warning- if you've decided the pros outweigh the cons, go for it.

Comment: @sh_newbie At least one bug I can see: if there is another group like `sudox` or `sudos` or whatever, any users in that group would be added to the `sudoers` file as well. Also, if there are many users in a group, the list of users might be too long to write to a file in an atomic way (meaning that a crash could leave the `sudoers` file in an invalid state).

Comment: Thanks Chris, food for thought there.